# REST API & NPSP error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION

Tags: rest-api, npsp

I have NPSP v3 set up in Salesforce and am using the REST API to create a contact record. I am inserting fields [FirstName], [LastName], [Email], [Phone], [MailingState], [MailingPostalCode], [RecordTypeId] only.

It works fine but I have a case that is throwing the error

> Error: call to URL
>   https://axysau.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Contact/
>   failed with status 400, response [{"message":"Failed to create Account
>   for Contact FIRSTNAME LASTNAME. You are creating a duplicate record.
>   We recommend you use an existing record
>   instead.","errorCode":"FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION","fields":[]}],
>   curl_error , curl_errno 0

It is failing for a case where the contact is already in Salesforce with a different email address. I have checked validation rules on `Account`, `Contact` and `npsp__Address__c` but none of them have any. I also checked 'Household Account Addresses Disabled' in NPSP Settings->People->Addresses. I still get the same error.

So I changed the postal code for that contact before its created with the API and it has successfully created the Contact & Account for them.

Where can I change settings so that contact with the same firstname, lastname & postal code as someone already in Salesforce doesn't block me from creating a new Contact & Account record for them? No doubt I will get the same people using a different email address, or different people with the same name living in the same suburb. I want it to create a new record in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the Duplicate Rules feature.  The error you're seeing is deceptive because the Duplicate Rule error is typically `DUPLICATES_DETECTED, Use one of these records`.

Check Setup to see if you have Duplicate Rules configured.  If you have active rules that are set to Allow, then go to the NPSP Settings tab > System Tools > Error Notifications and check the Respect Duplicate Rule Settings.

Comment: Thank you! I've disabled the Duplicate Rule on the Account object and I can successfully add the record now. I'll see about re-activating it and modifying the rules.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not Validation Rules but [Duplicate Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm).

NPSP is trying to create a Household Account for each Contact you insert. However, the Account creation is being blocked by the Duplicate Rule on Account, likely meaning that you already have a Household Account by that name. You may wish to [customize Duplicate Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_prevention_map_of_tasks.htm&type=5) to change the criteria used to identify duplicate records to be more rigorous, or even deactivate it entirely.

Comment: Thank you! I've disabled the Duplicate Rule on the Account object and I can successfully add the record now. I'll see about re-activating it and modifying the rules as you've specified.